# Missing compile error in Obj-C with protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, protocols

In my memory, when a method of protocol is not implemented, XCode generate a compilation error but when now is just show a "warning".

Is there a change about this ? Is it about XCode configuration ? I would like to throw a compilation error when a method of (required) protocol is not implemented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the "Treat Warnings as Errors" build setting to `Yes`:

[image]

This can also be done by passing `-Werror` as a compiler argument.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I had some others minors warnings which are now treat as errors but it responds to my answer ;-)

Comment: You should fix ALL warnings. They should never be treated as "minor".